# Ant build script not seeing refid

Tags: ant, build, reference

I have a build.xml file that includes a common.xml file that defines some refid values. However, my task cannot see the refid value. I have not been able to find a solution on the web and am looking for some help.

I call the genbeans target in the build.xml file. It fails on the xmlbean taskdef with the message Reference my_classpath_jars not found.

build.xml

```
----------------------------
[includes common.xml]


**my_classpath_jars fails to be seen at this point - defined in common.xml**

    <taskdef name="xmlbean" classname="org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean">
        <classpath refid="my_classpath_jars"/>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Generate the XMLBeans java code from our source XSD file(s) -->
    <target name="genbeans" description="Generate XML Bean files" depends="build_my_jar_cpath">
        <mkdir dir="${lib}"/>
        <xmlbean destfile="${lib}/${appname}Beans.jar" failonerror="true">
            <classpath refid="my_classpath_jars"/>
            <fileset dir="src/XSD Files" includes="*.xsd, *.wsdl"/>
        </xmlbean>
    </target>


common.xml
-----------------------------
  <target name="build_my_jar_cpath">
    <path id="my_classpath_jars">
      <fileset dir="${jardir}"  includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep="${path.separator}" property="myjar.clpath" refid="my_classpath_jars"/>
  </target>
```

Comment: Before calling your target, try to see if your refids are even defined You can use <property refid=`xx`/> to set a property to that reference id. By the way, you normally use `id=` when you set the id and `refid=` when you get the id.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use the `ant -d` switch when calling your target. You'll see a ton of output. Save it to a file and parse through it.

Do that, and the first thing you'll notice in the output is that it's defining your `taskdef`**before** you have defined your `my_classpath_jars`. That `my_classpath_jars` refid is only set when you call that `greenbeans` target. Your `<taskdef>` is executed before any of your targets are called.

Either take the definition of `my_classpath_jars` out of the target `greenbeans`, or put your `<taskdef>` in there.